# how to build a hibernate multiple restriction In query with Criteria

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am currently building a query and I have to use the Criteria object from hibernate. Basically my native query is below:

```
select * from HDR where app_no in (select appNo from perm where code in (select code from access where appCode = 'P' and catId in :dymanicParam))
```

Any idea how to build the native query stated above by using org.hibernate.Criteria?

Thanks a lot for response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try do this

```
DetachedCriteria accessCriteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Access.class)
         .setProjection(Property.forName("code"))
         .add(Restrictions.eq("appCode", "P"))
         .add(Restrictions.eq("catId", dymanicParam));

DetachedCriteria permCriteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Perm.class)
         .setProjection(Property.forName("appNo"))
         .add(Property.forName("code").in(accessCriteria))

DetachedCriteria criteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(HDR.class)
         .add(Property.forName("app_no").in(permCriteria))

// criteria.getExecutableCriteria(session).list();
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for response but I am using hibernate 4.1.0.Final and on this line .add(Restrictions.in("code", accessCriteria)) I have compilation error -The method in(String, Object[]) in the type Restrictions is not applicable for the arguments (String, DetachedCriteria)

Comment: Oh, i'm sorry. i changed `Property.forName("app_no").in(permCriteria)`, `Property.forName("code").in(accessCriteria)`.
I did not have a class so I could not compile it myself.  Choose me!